# I want to convert pdf to text. but it gives me error. why spatie/pdf-to-text is showing error?

Tags: php, laravel, pdftotext

my code

```
<?php 
require_once 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;

echo Pdf::getText('simple.pdf');
```

error message

> Fatal error: Uncaught Spatie\PdfToText\Exceptions\CouldNotExtractText: The command ""/usr/bin/pdftotext" simple.pdf -" failed. Exit Code: 1(General error) Working directory: C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf Output: ================ Error Output: ================ The system cannot find the path specified. in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text\src\Pdf.php:73 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text\src\Pdf.php(84): Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf->text() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\index.php(7): Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf::getText('simple.pdf') #2 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdf\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text\src\Pdf.php on line 73

Comment: Your stack trace is pretty explicit; `The system cannot find the path specified.` in relation to `"/usr/bin/pdftotext`

Comment: I'm a beginner. Please elaborate it for me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Actually you need to pass proper path of your pdf file in Pdf::getText()

Comment: I'm so dumb that i couldn't solve it. what is actual code that will save me. Plz help me @KhalidKhan

Comment: Don't say like that. it happens with everyone

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`pdftext` is a .exe file located in your system. Find the path of this file and 
then put path like this and pass it to `getText` method like this

```
$path = 'c:/Program Files/Git/mingw64/bin/pdftotext';
echo Pdf::getText('simple.pdf', $path);
```

I hope it'll help you

> Note: $path this should be your path of pdftext.exe file