# Spatie PdftoText cant find path of library (windows)

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to use Spatie pdf-to-text package.

this is my Controller code

```
  public function TextFromPdf(Request $pdfFile)
    {


        if (isset($pdfFile)) {

            $file = $pdfFile->file('pdfFile');
            $fileName =  'PDF File '.time() . '-' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
            $file->storeAs('',$fileName);
            $filePath =  Storage::disk('local')->path($fileName);
           
            $text = (new Pdf ('C:\CV-Test\blog\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text'))
                ->setPdf($filePath)
                ->text();
             return view('CV_test.pdf', compact('text'));
        }


    }
```

the error I am getting is this

> The command "C:\CV-Test\blog\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text
> "C:\CV-Test\blog\storage\app\PDF File
> 1621335323-19DE0310_04_zpl_sued_mediathek.pdf" -" failed. Exit Code:
> 1(General error) Working directory: C:\CV-Test\blog\public Output:
> ================ Error Output: ================ Der Befehl "C:\CV-Test\blog\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text" ist entweder falsch
> geschrieben oder konnte nicht gefunden werden.

It means the path C:\CV-Test\blog\vendor\spatie\pdf-to-text is wrong or can't found. What I understood from the documentation that I need to put the path to pdftotext library. Here is a screenshot of where my package is located it's in the vendor folder

[Folder structure Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MfNSE.png)

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks, in advance.

Comment: what happen if you use `new Pdf()` without any params

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? I would assume that you haven't installed the binary properly - ensure that you are using the Windows version!

Comment: i just used the command "composer require spatie/pdf-to-text" to add the package i thought thats enought to use it.

Comment: @KamleshPaul when i use just `$text =new Pdf ()` and then `print_r($text)` it says **Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf Object ( [pdf:protected] => [binPath:protected] => /usr/bin/pdftotext [options:protected] => Array ( ) )**

Comment: oh then probably it is for `linux` you need to check if it work on windows or not. you can take a look this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058603/i-want-to-convert-pdf-to-text-but-it-gives-me-error-why-spatie-pdf-to-text-is

Comment: Thats strange apperantly i am not an expert but it was never the case if i require a package in laravel  project that it was depending on operating system. I always could start using it since it was in the context of laravel framework. Furthermore the documentation doesnt restrict the OS. However thanks for the link. I saw it already but unfortunatly i wasnt helpful at the end. How can i find out if it works for windows ? :( Is there another package i can use which you guys are aware of?

Comment: ill try using this one here : https://github.com/christian-vigh-phpclasses/PdfToText

Comment: Just have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59058603/i-want-to-convert-pdf-to-text-but-it-gives-me-error-why-spatie-pdf-to-text-is and ensure that you've installed the neccessary binary

Comment: Man, you are my hero. I was just too dump to find the bianries. I have downloaded it and now its working :) Thaaanks soo much brooo.

Answer (score 2):

The binaries for Windows can be downloaded at this page:

https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html in Section **Download the Xpdf command line tools:**

When unpacked, just use this code

`$text = (new Pdf('Path\to\pdftotext.exe'))->setPdf($pdfFilePath)->text();`

and replace the paths.