# Spatie\PdfToText\Exceptions\CouldNotExtractText

Tags: laravel, github, pdftotext

I'm trying to get text from my pdf stored in public folder 'cv'. I'm using the Spatie library from GitHub, but it doesn't work for me.

**This is the error message:**
[image]

**This is my code:**

```
use Spatie\PdfToText\Pdf;

 $text = (new Pdf())
            ->setPdf(public_path('cv'), $newPDF)
            ->text();
```

**My folder of pdfs:**

[image]

Comment: Could you include your error message as text instead of an image please? It helps people searching for the issue you're having on Google to find the relevant question

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing Unix style paths and Windows style paths.

Windows uses back slashes `\` and Unix uses forward slashes `/` to separate folders.

Change `$newPDF` from `cv/php1A57.tmp.pdf` to `cv\php1A57.tmp.pdf`

You'll also need to make sure you've installed pdftotext. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67587222/6632744) suggests downloading it from [here](https://www.xpdfreader.com/download.html).

As the answer also suggests, you'll need to change the path to the pdftotext binary like this:

```php
$text = (new Pdf('Path\to\pdftotext.exe'))
    ->setPdf(public_path('cv'), $newPDF)
    ->text();
```

Comment: hi, thanc you for notice.. but I use windows

Comment: @FZ_ZID Yes, you're using Windows, but the path style you're using is Unix. That's what you're doing incorrectly.